# Are there audits in the triage review queue?

Tags: support, review-audits, triage

The other queues have audits to check whether reviewers are properly reviewing. So does the new triage review queue also have audits?

Comment: Haven't found one *yet*. But it's early days, I'm sure they will be added soon.

Comment: I reviewed 20 questions and there was no audit. We'll see ...

Comment: I've been active today in several review queues and I was challenged with audits in all of them, except the triage queue (although I also maxed up at 20 here). So I strongly suspect there are no audits in place there, at least for now.

Comment: I hope it will stay audit-free. I stopped reviewing because of frustration with the audit system. Let's have one review queue with no badges, no other rewards, and no audits.

Comment: @Patricia, I'm afraid badges are already granted for this review queue. Therefore, audits will probably end up being necessary.

Comment: People would probably review poorly without badges anyway.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of this afternoon, there are audits in the Triage queue:

- **Known-good** audits are based on [a test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196949/request-for-review-close-reopen-known-good-audits) I ran a while back to find a better source of audit questions for the Close and Reopen queues. If it works out here, it may be re-used elsewhere; known-good audits have been a bit of a sore point in the past.
- **Known-bad** audits are based on spam, just as in the Low Quality review queue. They're pretty awful.

We're still tweaking the *exact* criteria here, but it should be pretty easy to avoid failing audits in either of these categories.

Comment: Curious to know how we'll deal with polarizing junk -- the type of question that many will think of as unsalvageable trash but which still get accepts as good enough on grounds that a short majority found it OK looking.

Comment: Probably *not* via lots of hyperbolic meta posts.

Comment: I was going to create a discussion post asking the community whether we should enable audits in this queue (apparently some people liked the audit-free nature of this queue), and if so, what algorithm we should use to get audit cases. However, I stopped thinking that it would be downvoted and closed as a duplicate of this post anyway. My suggestion for an algorithm was to use old real reviews that had been **unanimously** reviewed with the same result. Should I have created that post?

Comment: There are now audits in the queue.

Comment: Indeed there are, @Alex - updated!

Comment: I've tested that technique in the past, @deleteme - the results were pretty poor for "known good" audits. The best of the worst tend to not be all that great.

Comment: It is indeed "pretty easy to avoid failing audits", especially if - as is often the case - the post was "asked 5 mins ago" and has a comment dating from "yesterday". The easy way out is now to click on "link" and take a look at the votes/comments. Following the community judgement on SO may sometimes make you believe that ["4+8+5+1+3=22"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727671), but you are sure to pass the audit :)