# Banned for marking question as "Should Be Improved"

Tags: support

I have a disagreement with an automated evaluation of my review as "incorrect". Normally, I try to see why I was deemed "incorrect" and just let the judgement slide if I disagree. But, in this case, I have been banned from reviewing for 2 days.

Here is the [review audit failure](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7481749), and here is the (now-deleted) question itself:

> ### Take from both sides thing from : [PHP]
>
> ---
>
> I have:
>   Loerum upsum damn da da, Loreum upsum.
>   Loreum upsumLoreum upsum
>   **test1 : value1**
>   **test1 : value1 asdasdasd**
>   **asdasdas test2 : value2**
>   **test3 : value3**
>   Loerum upsum damn da da, Loreum upsum.
>   Loreum upsumLoreum upsum
>   And how i can take from : both sides? it from both side to array: (exp: key=test1; value=value1)
>
> ---
>
> deleted by Bill the Lizard♦ Mar 6 at 15:14

I chose to mark the question as "Should Be Improved" because the desired functionality is not clear, there is no stated "problem", and there is no evidence of an attempt to solve a problem.

However, there is a request to achieve some functionality. It seems that the OP wants to split text that is separated by a colon into key/value pairs. In my opinion, that request just needs to be clarified and, ideally, an attempt at a solution should be made.

The system claimed that I failed the review audit because the question is clearly non-sensical and cannot be improved (I'm paraphrasing). However, I am fairly confident that I understand the question, and it is not non-sensical at all. I just think it needs to be clarified (i.e. improved).

The same user has posted a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903092/regex-help-find-between-text), and it has not been removed. In fact, it has been answered and the answer has been up-voted and accepted. Clearly, this new post is an "improved" version of the original post that was deemed "un-improvable".

I realize that my ban is not based solely on that one review audit. Still, in general I feel that I often (not always) disagree with the automated determination of failure.

Is there any recourse for removing my two-day ban?

### EDIT

The comment debate over the validity of the OP's original question has become irrelevant. However the *amount* of debate should draw attention to the *subjectivity of the review process*.

I am **not** looking for the question to be re-instated or un-deleted. I'm looking for a human to look at my ban and say, "Hey. I can see how that's subjective," and to remove it. Automated bans do not account for the subjectivity inherent in the review process.

If my ban cannot be removed, I'll just wait it out. And I'll try not to let it sour my interest in reviewing posts or participating in the community at large.

Comment: Can a 10k user post the contents of the deleted question here?

Comment: thats the entire thing quoted

Comment: People marking questions like this as needs improvement is exactly why the help and improvement queue is an effectively useless queue as there's almost nothing there but questions that we can't possibly salvage.

Comment: wow.  That is really hard to understand.  I personally would have flagged unclear what you're asking.  And because of the nature of the inputs (nonsensical latin), some might have even marked spam (which is probably how it became an audit).

Comment: @Servy That may be so, but this question could easily be improved. If I had come across it in the "Help and Improvement" queue, I would have edited it myself. I can rephrase the question in a more understandable way with one sentence (as I have in my question). In short, saying that "we can't possibly salvage" the question is subjective at best and, in my opinion, fallacious.

Comment: @ryanyuyu It's not "non-sensical" latin. It's [lorem ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum), a widely accepted demonstration of sample text.

Comment: @showdev I did not know that.  And my guess is that at least one other user also did not know that and marked as spam.  This would not have been turned into an audit [unless it was marked as spam](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278440/are-there-audits-in-the-triage-review-queue/278512#278512).

Comment: @ryanyuyu I don't think ignorance of a topic should be a cause for removal of a question. That completely defeats this community.

Comment: @showdev neither do I, but there is a reasonable limit to what to expect from our users.  Keep in mind SO is supposed to be in English, so Latin is not acceptable.  At least when it's not clear that it's sample text (as is the case in this really unclear question).

Comment: @showdev Looking at the question it doesn't look like the Loerum upsum text was part of the actual sample text, but rather text that the OP just jammed into the question to get around minimum character length and the low quality threshold limits.

Comment: I don't think it's relevant that Loren ipsum is Latin, because the entire point of it is a placeholder. Obviously it's hard to make an argument about what is or is not "common knowledge," but I would tend to think that Lorem Ipsum is, among the relevant communities.

Comment: @ryanyuyu By that logic, PHP code should not be acceptable because it is not English.

Comment: @showdev Please consider that the point I was trying to make is that _someone must have marked it as spam_ which (perhaps unfairly) turned this into an audit.  And answers [must be in English](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262014/how-to-deal-with-non-english-posts/262054#262054) so anyone mistaking the "sample data" for actual question text would close it for not being English.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I see your point. Thanks for clarifying. Please see my edit to my post.

Comment: @ryanyuyu a deleted post by anyone other than the author themselves can become a 'known bad' audit in first post and late answer.  Mods, community, or 10k users can delete questions. Spam flags are one of the many ways this can happen, but not the only.

Comment: @MichaelT is there any place to reference that?  The only thing I could find in search was about Spam being used as the basis of triage audits.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I appear to be in error... though not by much: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/213963 -- a VLQ flag, NAA, or Spam flag and removed by moderator will do it (including Community).  Considering that many things auto-generate VLQ flags (not sure if its user flagged only that feeds that). I doubt that this question was flagged as spam but rather VLQ... which it is. That also may have changed in the nearly a year since its writing.

Comment: @MichaelT Ok thanks.  Then like half of my comments are irrelevant/wrong since there are other avenues for becoming an audit in triage.  Obviously for Triage NAA is not applicable, but maybe VLQ.

Comment: @ryanyuyu note that a lot of the process around triage and help and improvement is focused on moving handling of system/queue VLQ flags by the community rather than the mods ( http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/289086 ). If a mod got that question in the H&I on day 1 (this was day 1 or 2), then they may have tried to help remove the worst offenders by deleting them... which would have generated known bad audits. Note that if it was down voted, closed, and the Community Roomba script deleted it, this would have the same effect.

Comment: The [lorem ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) debate is hilarious I nearly fell off my chair!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

That... Was a pretty bad question. But it shouldn't have been an audit. Careful reading does indicate that it was likely intended as a question (and, critically, *not* intended to test the waters for future spam posting by dropping a pile of nonsense onto the site).

"Should Be Improved" is a stretch here; it'd take a fairly heroic edit to make that into a good question. Still, there's no denying it *needs* improvement, and in theory at least it could get it - therefore, your review was acceptable; I've lifted the ban and removed this question from the pool for future audits.

That said, I would strongly encourage you to think twice before choosing this option on similar questions in the future. If you feel strongly that there's real hope for a given question, great; otherwise, best to take out the trash early on. I'm highly skeptical that even someone as skilled as you could've actually salvaged that question; if there's no **real** hope, then "Should be Improved" just needlessly prolongs the agony.

Comment: Thanks very much, Shog9. After the debate here, I feel I have a better understanding of how "Should Be Improved" is intended to be used. Any community site as popular as SO will have a plethora of pollution (to varying subjective degrees), so I absolutely agree that "Should Be Improved" is best reserved for questions with more obvious (or objective) potential for improvement. Thanks again.

Comment: I also hadn't considered: If a question is deleted, a determined OP will investigate the reason, make necessary changes, and repost it in a better form. Reposting an improved version of a deleted question can have the same result as editing a closed question to get it re-opened. If the OP doesn't repost the question, it probably wasn't very useful to begin with. So, as you've said, it's best to "take out the trash early on" -- better to have a good question deleted and reposted than to push a bad question onto an already congested repair queue.

Comment: @showdev OP can even edit that deleted question (only self-deleted questions can't be edited, this limitation is in order to prevent abuse) and if they feel edit improved it sufficiently, flag for moderator to undelete after done. This is almost like repost but has the benefit of moderator review (flag decline would mean repost would be not a good idea) and "cleaner" posting history if moderator accepts and undeletes (history plays role in asking rate limits)

Comment: I don't follow Meta much so the outsider in me wonders if  "Should be improved"  should really be named "Could be improved".

Comment: @ChristopherPainter [Don't mistake it with could be improved](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287024/difference-between-should-be-improved-and-unsalvageable-in-triage/287026#287026)

Comment: I disagree that "anything could be improved"....

Answer (score 26):

There appears to be a misunderstanding about what "should be improved" means.

> **Should Be Improved** for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable

This means that the author or others can edit the question into an answerable question.  It means the author can edit it or someone else can edit it to be an answerable question.  If the author doesn't make any changes (often the case and the purpose of Help and Improvement), you are saying that someone else can fix the question. By selecting that the post is "should be improved" you are creating a task in the Help and Improvement queue for someone to edit it.

Should be improved should ***only*** be used where ***anyone*** can possibly edit the question into something useful.  If the question can ***only*** be improved by the original author, "should be improved" is creating an unnecessary task (and increases the angst of people who are trying to help).

If the question can only be improved by the original author, the question should be closed with the appropriate close reason (possibly through the unsalvageable option) so that the author is clearly informed of what needs to be fixed and those who are trying to help are not besieged with questions that they cannot fix.

If the question is not clear, it is not clear.  Without guidance from the original author, you cannot read their mind to make it a clear question.

If the question is asking someone to write all the code for them, without giving the current code they are working on in the form of an mcve, it should be closed with the appropriate off topic reason.  You don't have access to their code to put the mcve in the question... and if they don't have the code then its *really* off topic and they should instead be hiring you to write code for them rather than fix their question.

And so on.

Help and Improvement is not restricted to mind readers.  Don't send them questions that require such.

If you think you can rewrite the question from scratch better, don't guess as to what the author is asking without guidance... go ask that question yourself.

Comment: From the OP: "If I had come across it in the "Help and Improvement" queue, I would have edited it myself. I can rephrase the question in a more understandable way with one sentence (as I have in my question)".  OP clearly believes that it can be edited by anyone to improve it.

Comment: Again, I could have rewritten it. If I had encountered the question in the "Help and Improvement" queue, I would have. I imagine that others could have done the same. No "mind-reading" is necessary. Look at the OPs sample input and output and extrapolate the desired functionality.

Comment: @showdev Questions need to be clear and have an objectively correct answer.  That someone could have taken a wild guess at what the OP might have wanted is not an appropriate question.  It needs clarification from the author on what is actually being asked.  And that's on top of the complete and total mess that is the presentation of the answer.  Some help is one thing, but at a certain point the question becomes not worth trying to save.

Comment: @MichaelT `If you think you can rewrite the question from scratch better, don't guess as to what the author is asking without guidance... go ask that question yourself.` If SO worked exclusively that way, one supreme mod would be asking all the questions. Every question involves a degree of interpretation.

Comment: @showdev There are sufficiently well written questions that don't need to be rewritten that do a good job of presenting themselves in a way that can be objectively answered. Trying to rewrite an open question without the guidance of the OP about what they are actually asking is not a good thing because many times you will be completely wrong (gotta love those XY problems). Once it is closed however, that's another story. But close it first rather than try to improve it.

Comment: @MichaelT I don't completely disagree (especially about XY problems). The community at large (ostensibly) decides whether a question is well-written and does a "good job" of presenting itself or whether it needs to be rewritten. However, the decision to ban me for two days was **not** made by the community -- it was made by a bot, which may not be appropriate in this context.

Comment: @showdev it was made based on heuristics that were feed with the information that you have several times failed triage audits recently. Realize also that marking questions that need mind reading or should otherwise be closed ("write this code for me") for "needs improvement" generates extra work for those people who are trying to help new users with stuff they can't fix (that you want to or could fix this one isn't at issue here). Review ban on one and only one bad audit would be an issue - you likely failed several others.

Comment: @MichaelT Yes, I understand all of that. I still don't think this particular case should have triggered a ban. By the way, I am **one of** "those people who are trying to help new users". By insinuating that I'm creating "extra work" by encouraging people to THINK rather than just REACT is, in my opinion, a distasteful and disrespectful attitude. Anyway, I'm tired of arguing and there is work to be done. See you in two days.

Comment: `"If the question is asking someone to write all the code for them, without giving the current code they are working on in the form of an mcve, it should be closed with the appropriate off topic reason."` which off-topic reason is appropriate for that? quite a lot of the questions in the triage queue will fall into this category, and I flag them as too broad but those flags typically just age away.

Comment: @TZHX it is a possible interpretation of `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.` which directs the OP how to fix the question by including an mcve. You've got code (programming is the art of debugging an empty file), and we need the clear problem statement, error and code to fix.

Comment: ... the advantage of this over too broad (which is also correct) is that it provides specific direction about what is needed.  First, we need code - it needs to be minimal, complete, and verifiable (and here's a link to how to create this example). Second, we need a clear problem statement of what is trying to be solved. Third, we need an error.  Lacking these three things, there is no useful question. It also sets the expectation that we are for *debugging* help, not *write this from scratch for me* help.

Comment: Thank you. I think that close-reason specifying *debugging help* probably put me off using it, as a lot of the questions are just "how do I..." without any attempt made or problem posed. I will use this reason in the future.

Answer (score 10):

One important thing to remember is that (unless I'm quite mistaken, in which case someone can correct me) hitting Should Be Improved sends the post to the Help and Improvement queue. Sending something there implies that someone ***other than the poster*** may be able to edit it into a good question. This could theoretically be edited into an on-topic question, but the likelihood of someone other than the poster doing so is fairly low. As such, it seems to me that it would be much more appropriate to put it on hold as "unclear what you're asking" until the original poster clarifies what they're asking.

Comment: Is that how that works?  Marking as "Needs Improvement" from Triage sends it to Help and Improvement?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is - someone can correct me if I'm wrong. But I thought that that's what feeds the Help and Improvement queue.

Comment: And the help for "Needs Improvement" mentions __edits by the author or others__

Comment: Fair enough, sphanley. That makes sense. But it still seems like a fuzzy judgement call and, in this context, banning a real human user for two days seems inappropriate from an automated system.

Comment: I agree that there's lots of audits that are fuzzy, and that can be frustrating. But as you said yourself, a ban isn't triggered just by failing a single audit. What I've come to keep in mind is that almost everything "needs improvement" - you've just got to decide if needs a *reasonable* amount of improvement or an *unreasonable* amount.

Comment: @sphanley I can agree with that. I'll take that into account in the future. But it feels a bit like trying to guess an answer on "Family Feud" (e.g. how did the lowest common denominator answer this survey), which is sadly deficient for a site that revolves around technical knowledge. I guess that just because I feel I can improve the question, doesn't mean that someone else can/will.

Comment: @ryanyuyu By that logic every single post one could ever construct would merit NI.  I mean someone posting spam could always edit it into something reasonable.  The whole point of marking something as NI is to put the post in front of reviewers that can work to fix the post into a quality post.  When you put trash in front of those reviewers you just make the HI queue that much less useful, and do nothing to actually improve the post itself.  It needs to be closed as unclear until the author salvages it, and marking it as NI doesn't do that.

Comment: @Servy I'm not saying that the logic is correct, nor that I think this particular post should be improved.  It is "unclear what you're asking".  I'm pointing out what the _actual help box_ for "Needs improvement" says.  Quote: **Should Be Improved for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable**

Comment: @Servy `I mean someone posting spam could always edit it into something reasonable.` I disagree. I could not edit "gmail help phone number 800-###-####" advertisements or "so-and-so is a loser" spam posts into useful questions. But I could edit a malformed or convoluted request (like the post in question) into an arguably *improved* question.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables you should give the latest podcast a listen - it describes the workflow and some of the problems people have with the H&I queue.  And yes, three "needs improvement" means that a review task in H&I is generated for someone to edit into a proper question.  But, if only the OP can fix it... it might be better to flag it for closing (and yes, the triage workflow for that is poor) so that the OP can get notified it needs to be fixed.

Comment: @ryanyuyu So you're taking an action that you know to be actively destructive because the wording of a brand new feature (still in beta) says so?

Comment: @showdev Of course someone could edit a spam post into a useful question, or at least an "improved" question, to use your wording.  It'd basically be re-writing it from scratch, which is effectively the same as your example.  NI is for posts that can reasonably be improved into quality content, not just posts that can be edited to be less terrible.

Comment: @MichaelT - good to know, thanks.  I'll have to see if "Queue is pointless, since none of the questions can be improved" and "Queue prone to misuse, due to badge farming" are the top two complaints.

Comment: @Servy No I'm not!!  I'm pointing out that what this answers claim is not at all what the actual text says.  Is there any standing feature request to edit the now obsolete text for "Should Be Improved"?  My pointing this inconsistency out does not mean I'm taking either side.  Like I repeatedly said, this question is clearly "Unclear what you're askiing".

Comment: @Servy `It'd basically be re-writing it from scratch` Exactly. That's not improving. That's just coming up with a question out of thin air. That is *not* the same as my example. The OP is asking for specific functionality, not just posting gibberish or spam. This is evidenced by his [*acceptable* rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903092/regex-help-find-between-text), which someone was obviously able to understand, answer, and have accepted.

Comment: @showdev In your example the question is functionally being re-written entirely from scratch.  Virtually nothing of the original is remaining.  And even after this re-write it's not even close to a quality question, it's just a marginal and "not terrible" question.

Comment: @Servy That's because the OP used an *example* of what he wants instead of a *description* of that functionality. That doesn't make it spam or gibberish. But, I'd agree it's still marginal because there's no attempt at self-solution.

Comment: @showdev You keep claiming that I'm claiming it's spam or gibberish.  I'm not.  I'm just saying it needs the OP to basically re-write it becuase it's completely lacking in information and is unclear to the point of not being answerable.  That the OP was able to re-write it in response is in no way an indication that we should have re-written it for him.  It needed him to re-write it, and he re-wrote it.  That is accomplished by marking it as "unclear' and not NI.

Comment: @Servy Perhaps I misunderstood or am reading too much into your comments. However, you did reference people making "spam posts" and equated my example to "re-writing" such a post from scratch. You also referred to the OPs question as being "trash" that shouldn't be put in the Help queue.

Comment: @showdev I said that if someone posted spam, they could salvage that post.  And that's true.  And your example post is trash, in the sense that it's a worthless question of negative value to the community and that is most certainly not worth spending considerable effort trying to salvage.

Comment: @Servy Re-writing a spam post is not "salvage". It is replacement. Your judgement that the example post is "trash", "worthless", and "of negative value" is completely subjective. The three up-votes on the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903092/regex-help-find-between-text) indicate some perceived usefulness. The OP improved his question and the question was usefully answered.

Comment: @showdev That question is one of the much bemoaned "write a regex for me" set which seem to get lots of answers from FGITW practitioners.  That particular one has an objective answer... on the other hand, this one is asking for someone to write not just a regex, but a fair bit of additional code around it in php. This question should be closed as "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself..." until the OP provides the mcve.

Comment: @showdev The deleted question is what I called trash and worthless.  The OP's complete re-write (functionally replacing the whole thing, something you're saying is "not salvage") is a question I called mediocre and "not terrible".

Comment: @Servy Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: @MichaelT I agree. The question is asking for free labor. I'm not requesting that question be un-deleted. I just wanted a reasonable moderator to remove my ban. It was worth a shot.

Comment: @ryanyuyu It's test data. Would you close/delete a question containing afdfdsgfdsgfd? Or downvote/NAA an answer with same?

Comment: @showdev I think you're completely correct in thinking the question could be salvaged. If there was a spam flag, that would likely blindside the moderator, "here's a spam flag, which someone has thoughtfully raised, looks (at brief glance) like rubbish"

Comment: @BillWoodger uh is this for my comments above?  Anyway to answer your question, I would  vote to close_only if it was unclear that the "test data" is actually test data and not part of the question's text_.  If I though your question was literally "What is fjosdfjoskdjfokjsdokfjksjdof" I would vote to close.  If it was clear that `var fakeString = "fjosdfjoskdjfokjsdokfjksjdof";` then obviously not.

Comment: @BillWoodger I agree. There's a discrepancy on SO between necessary subjective human response based on thought and opinion and automated computer judgments based solely on algorithms. That is, someone's thoughtful opinion should not *necessarily* result in an automated ban.

Comment: @BillWoodger, nobody suggested that this should have been flagged as **spam**. I'm not sure why people are acting like that was suggested.

Comment: :-) I read that it was spam: on the internet.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes, I must have fat-fingered the location of where to comment. Same with my other comment. Somehow scrolled down too far... Your response is less than clarifying. The example is neither that you mention in response, yet you said it should be closed for not being in English?

Comment: @BillWoodger yes [non-English questions should be closed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262054/4320665).  But not that this question was not English.  Just that it was so poorly worded/formatted that I could see someone mistakenly thinking, as I did, that the question itself was not English (instead of sample data).

Comment: @sphanley I think that's partly my fault.  I pointed out that one way it could have become an audit was a spam flag (that did not necessarily happen).  Potentially someone misinterpreted my [possibly erroneous](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288773/banned-for-marking-question-as-should-be-improved/288774?noredirect=1#comment169487_288773) observation as a judgment.

Answer (score 0):

The question is at best a duplicate. It shouldn't be improved but closed against the duplicate.

It's also of generic matter. Most likely has been posted because - for whatever reason - the user was not able to locate the information on the site. As this does matter for Q&A it should have been downvoted and voted to delete in review.

I can't say about your ban, but needs improvement is a pretty unicorn in rainbow land style. not at all wrong, but with no expected outcome, right?