# "Should be improved" is explained badly in Triage queue

Tags: discussion, triage

There is an explanation for the *Should be improved* option in the *Triage* queue as follows:

> **Should Be Improved** for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable

However, [posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288775/878514) on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287026/878514) strongly discourages marking posts as *Should be improved* in cases when only author could possibly make the question better (for example, there is too few informations and only OP is able to add them).

Such questions should be marked *Unsalvageable*, but for new users it is not so clear. Explanation for the first option clearly states that if the *edits by the author [...] would result in a question that is clear* then the question *Should be improved*.

I also found myself using this option in a wrong way because of it.

Comment: Related: [this feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288779/rephrase-triage-help-text-for-should-be-improved-and-unsalvageable)

Comment: Not really clear on where you're getting lost here. Got an example where you feel the guidance led you wrong?