# Spam flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, spam

This was from a while ago, but I remembered about it and wanted to ask:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351570/i-have-an-array-thats-have-a-dictionary-and-dictionary-have-some-object-i-wan) is the question. I flagged it as spam because the second half of the question seems to be semi-spam (or just very low-quality, irrelevant text) along with what seems to be a plug for Aldus Pagemaker. It seems like a low-quality advertisement to me, yet my flag was declined as `a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it`.

Could I get an explanation as to why my thought process is incorrect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its not spam at all. The text is a sample describing the kind of formatting they want (probably should have been in a block-quote though). I added the block-quote to make it clearer.

"Lorem Ipsum" is classic sample text, and is copied verbatim from the web. Googling the first phrase gives these results: [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=Lorem%20Ipsum%20is%20simply%20dummy%20text%20of%20the%20printing%20and%20typesetting%20industry.&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN) and the text can be found as the first paragraph of the first [result](http://lipsum.com/).

It looks like a crappy question for sure, but no indications of spam from what I can see.

Comment: Yes, definitely could have benefited from a lot of formatting.  The "block-quote" especially, so that the bottom half is correctly interpreted as the __expected output__.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yeah, I didn't think to google it. I just thought that the actual question ended at `I want my text like this in UITextView.` and the rest was spam. It wasn't clear to me that the bottom half was *expected output*.

Comment: @Jashaszun no worries.  [I've actually made a very similar mistake.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288773/banned-for-marking-question-as-should-be-improved#comment169439_288773)

Comment: Yes, just dummy Lorem Ipsum text, you can generate the same thing on sites like [getlorem](https://getlorem.com)